# How to compute the following limit?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I need to find a maximum/minimum value of a function, and my basic calculus has failed me.

I have solved for an eiganvalue in terms of $a$, and need to know when that magnitude of that eigenvalue falls within a certain range based on $a$.

$$-4 \leq |\pm \sqrt{a^2-2a-1}-a |\leq 0$$

In other words, I also have to consider the complex part of this inequality and I am completely stumped.

I tried taking the limit of the thing to see if there was an assymptote but I can't even figure out how to do that. I've tried taking the derivative of the thing to see if it has a max or min that falls inside or outside the inequality. I've exhausted all the tricks I remember from calc 2. My professor doesn't like to help on these things, and I've spent 3-4 hours on this single part of a single question on a four part homework assignment. He would just tell me to "think more deeply about it", and then when I can't figure it out in time to turn it in, I'll lose all points even if I have work shown. I'm exhausted. Sorry, end rant.

Comment: There is no such thing as a complex inequality.

Comment: I'm confused, put $a = -1000$, then the inequality clearly doesn't hold.

Comment: I'm confused. That inequality only makes sense when the expression under the radical is nonnegative. You should be able to sketch a graph and do some algebra to find out when it's true. I don't know what you mean by :complex part"? Are you asking about the imaginary part of the square root when the expression is negative? Limits don't seem to have anything to do with the problem. Please edit the question to clarify. Perhaps include some numerical examples. (Don't respond in comments.)

Comment: As I said, the MAGNITUDE of the function in the inequality must fall within that range. Complex numbers have a magnitude. I have added the absolute value bars to clarify further.

Comment: $a \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: The MAGNITUDE is non-negative.